# how to detect VerticalOffset's changes?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using a `ScrollViewer` and want to know when `VerticalOffset`'s value changes. couldn't find an event. can I detect that?

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer">

</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Did you try `ScrollChanged` event?

Comment: please refer this stack overflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448643/windows-phone-7-scrollviewer-value-changed.
I think this will help you.

Comment: Are you trying to implement pull to refresh? Have you seen [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx) or [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e) might help. Telerik has a [good solution](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddataboundlistbox-features-pulltorefresh.html)

Comment: Hi @ShawnKendrot, I was hoping to catch your attention :) I saw those two examples, both are for getting more old data at the bottom. I need new data on top.also That rad control is a paid which I can't buy it. I can't implement it myself? thanks.

Comment: The first example is "pull to refresh", the second does do bottom, but could be modified to work at the top. The second uses the new LLS for WP8, so if you are not targeting WP7, I would recommend that

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are actually trying to do, but I wrote an article on the Nokia developer site that allows you to track the vertical offset of the scrollviewer and manipulate another UI element.
I guess it has all the needed info for your question?

Take a look at it here http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_keep_a_UI_element_in_view_when_scrolling_a_page_in_Windows_Phone

There are 2 important parts in that you must not forget, first in the scrollviewer set the property ManipulationMode to Control

```
ManipulationMode="Control"
```

Secondly to get hold of the vertical offset, you'll need to search for the VerticalScrollBar inside the ScrollViewer, like this:

```
_vBar = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ScrollViewer, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
_vBar.ValueChanged += _vBar_ValueChangedHandler;
```